# How Tomcat handles session internally?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

From my understanding, Servlet Containers handle session using some HTTP protocols like,

1. Hidden Form Fields
2. URL Rewriting
3. Cookies

I'm curious how **Apache Tomcat** handles the session internally, though it's irrelevant to average developers.

Is Tomcat using cookies or others also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905244/session-management-in-tomcat

Please refer to the above link

Comment: It's open source, you can go look at exactly what it does: http://tomcat.apache.org/svn.html

Comment: @cjstehno Thanks. Any idea where to begin with?

Comment: I see no reason why this is broad. I also can't understand how a seemingly good question is closed and downvoted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, Tomcat directly sends cookies in the HTTP response , like `SET COOKIE:JSESSIONID....` back to the browser and rewrites the URL to add a `JSESSIONID` parameter in it , for the first request, so that it can fall back on the later in case *cookies* are disabled in the client browser.

The next time if the browser requests the server with the `JSESSIONID` in its `request` , Tomcat will use the `JSESSIONID` cookie for maintaining the session.

You can overide the session cookie behavior in Tomcat by modifying *context.xml*:

```
<Context cookies="false">
</Context>
```

and disable the url re-writing the same way :

```
<Context disableURLRewriting="true">
</Context>
```

Even read this [Servlet Session Tracking with cookies (JSESSIONID)](http://lazyjavadev.blogspot.ie/2013/04/servlet-session-tracking-with-cookies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat sends cookies by default unless they are blocked by the user from the browser (though this practice is not encouraged). Moreover, the session cookies (JSESSIONID) that are created are not persistent cookies and they die off whenever that instance(window) of the browser is closed.