# Keycloak, get the users' information

Tags: jersey, keycloak

I have a jersey application running on a tomcat server and it has keycloak integrated in it.. My problem is that I'm trying to fetch the information of authenticated user but I'm having a hard time to find a solution. Most (if not all) of the solutions I have seen so far suggest to import `KeycloakPrincipal` and other things but that would have worked if keycloak was parts of my `pom.xml` file which isn't the case. Anybody has ran into this issue before?

Comment: So you haven't used any KC adapter in your application? How do you make the integration?

Comment: I followed this: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/tomcat-adapter.html

Comment: Have you already tried `KeycloakPrincipal`?

Comment: No, as it was not part of the configuration instructions

Comment: In fact, you won't be able to import that class without any adapter. I would indeed try to fetch it from the user session.

Comment: I mean quite sure what you mean, what user session? does jersey stores session?

Comment: Tomcat actually keeps a session id: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17834792/1199132 However I have never used the KC Tomcat adapter myself, so I'm afraid I won't be able to help you out...